# Adding network drives in C# as admin: disappear after logoff

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, network-drive

Ok, first of all: my task is, to map a network drive programmatically from a C# program that runs **as administrator**.

I managed to map a drive as my normal admin user without elevated privileges and it was still visible after logoff/reboot (even though it didn't reconnect, but that's a different story). I did this with the  `WNetAddConnection2` WinApi function and also with the `net use` command in cmd, just to check.

Sadly, both didn't work with elevated privileges. In this case the drive is added as it schould, but after a reboot it is completely gone.

Is it even possible to achieve this **with elevated privileges** or is there some Windows account magical stuff I don't know about that prevents that?

Here is the Code I used, setting all flags that should usually make the drive be remembered and also reconnected:

```
uint flags = (uint)(Flags.CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED | 
                    Flags.CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | 
                    Flags.CONNECT_COMMANDLINE | 
                    Flags.CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE);

NETRESOURCE NetworkResource = new NETRESOURCE();
oNetworkResource.dwType = ResourceType.RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
oNetworkResource.lpLocalName = Console.ReadLine() + ":";
oNetworkResource.lpRemoteName = @"\\[Server]\foo";
oNetworkResource.lpProvider = null;

Console.WriteLine(WNetAddConnection2(NetworkResource, "[Password]", @"[Domain]\[Username]", flags));
```

Comment: Most drives mapped as a user using like net map j:\ blah are remembered, your apps wont be..

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by that. It sounds like you're saying that network drives added by an application can never be remembered but that is wrong, so I guess I didn't completely understand you.

Comment: I believe by default app mapped drives are not persistent.. as you've shown no code, I cant tell if you have tried to make them so

Comment: I edited my question and added the code.

Comment: I believe the only way to make them persistent is the net map command... rather than api.. having had a quick re-read (which you could have done) none of them mention the drives being persistent

Comment: @BugFinder - " is the net map command... rather than api." - interesting how the "net map" do it ? not by using api ?!? :)

Comment: Sadly I dont understand your question.. the net map command is a command part of windows.. which you would trigger by a shell call in c# ... what specifically are you not able to do

Comment: @bug What he's saying is, under the hood, the "net map" command *has* to be implemented in terms of an API function. That's all that the command is doing internally, is calling some API function. So of course if it can be done using "net map", then it can be done by calling some API function. The trick is simply figuring out which one. And this would be a better solution than shelling out to run "net map" in almost every case.

Comment: Yeah, but net use (which is the actual name of the command) doesn't work as I want in privileged mode either. If the answer below is true (and why should the answerer lie?^^) then it seems to be almost impossible to achieve

Comment: @Snowfire - how i say - all what you need - impersonate calling thread with not elevated token. this is possible. interesting that in win10 many apps not worked if i call it from elevated user (say `edgee` when called under built-it admin or uac off) how i research by same reason.

Answer (score 2):

> it was still visible after logoff/reboot

this is because, when `CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE` flag used - called exported, but undocumented function `I_MprSaveConn` (from `mpr.dll`) which save in registry, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\<lpLocalName>` information which you pass to `WNetAddConnection2`. but `I_MprSaveConn` at very begin call function `bool IsElevatedCaller(PLUID )` and if function return `true` - it just exit, without saving in registry. so you absolute correct - when you call `WNetAddConnection2` from elevated process (*without impersonation*) - this connection not persist (info not saved in registry)

solution: you need got not elevated token (say from `explorer`) - open/duplicate (for `TokenImpersonation` type) and call `SetThreadToken`. in this case `IsElevatedCaller` (*can*) return false (it first try open thread token (only if it not exist - process token) ) and query opened token for `TokenElevationType` (and return true if `TokenElevationTypeFull` )

so this of course not documented, but current (i test) if you impersonate self thread with not elevated token (how you got it separate question) flag `CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE` will be worked well

Comment: You will probably also need to configure the [EnableLinkedConnections setting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx) in order for the remembered drive mappings to be visible to elevated processes.  Note that it is not appropriate for commercial software to configure this setting on end users computers, but it may be OK for an in-house setting.